# How should one manage a superclass with a very large number of subclasses?

Tags: data-structures

I was reading through older questions and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974598/java-int-to-represent-an-class) made me wonder how you would go about managing such a large number of subclasses (100+ in the example question) as there were several comments saying that it was very bad practice to do this with classes.

Simple example, a game like Minecraft - everything is a block, so there is a clear superclass. But each block type has its own attribute values for density, texture, weight, chance of appearing, etc, etc, as well as many which are subclass-specific. 
So if the game had several dozen types of blocks, how do you manage that in a "proper", OOP way?

Is there a better data structure to use rather than pure classes? If it's just tons of numerical attributes you could use something simpler (even just a config file), but chances are there will be code specific to many of the subclasses as well.

**NB** Since this is a slightly more general question and not something I have tried to implement, I'm not sure if this is better suited to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). If it is, let me know in a comment and I'll close the question and ask it there instead. I'm also not sure how to tag this, so feel free to edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could maybe use a graph data structure where the nodes are the "blocks" and node properties are the node's properties. If a "block" has some sub-structure then this might be expressed using (sub-)nodes associated with their parent node. Then you use factory methods that create the different kind of block nodes.

This is a very flexible approach, because the graph data structure remains always the same, but you shift complexity into managing and handling the differently configured nodes / graphs...

Comment: Since there are no more ideas from anyone, I'll mark this as accepted as it makes sense to handle large numbers of identical objects (e.g. blocks) as a group rather than individually.